# Why Images not loading, when trying to load from an array in react

Tags: reactjs, react-image

I have following code where i am trying to load images from Array, if i try to load a single image it works fine, but if i try to load multiple images it dosent show any image, tho my div `test` is in the dom.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Slider extends Component {

    render() {
        const myItems = [{source_image: '1.jpg'}, {source_image: '2.jpg'}, {source_image: '3.jpg'}];
        return (



                <div id="test">
                    {myItems.map(function (a) {

                            <img src={"images/"+a.source_image}/>
                        }
                    )}
                </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Slider;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget return in map:

```
{myItems.map(function (a) {
        return <img src={"images/"+a.source_image}/> // here
    })
}

{myItems.map(a => <img src={"images/"+a.source_image}/>)} //this is more clear, I think
```

Comment: thanks, i cant describe the stupidity feel that i got here.

Comment: Be more attentive :)